# How to copy a rendered video to an external drive (KDEnLive)

Tags: scripts, kdenlive

I want to call a script to **copy** a finished render *from KDEnLive into an external HDD*

I see the **Scripts** tab in the render dialog but I don't see anything for *assigning* a file to it.

I'm using **Ubuntu MATE 16.04** which is up to date.

This is the script but I misplaced one but figured out that the script has to be in a scripts folder inside the project folder, Thought I could add the last part to it

```
#! /bin/sh

RENDERER="/usr/bin/kdenlive_render"
MELT="/usr/bin/melt"

SOURCE_0="/home/user/Videos/Production/trasc_001.sh.mlt"
TARGET_0="file:///home/user/Documents/Arts/Production/apps/untitled.mp4"
PARAMETERS_0="-pid:10320 $MELT atsc_1080p_30 avformat - $SOURCE_0 $TARGET_0 properties=x264-medium preset=veryfast crf=20 ab=160k threads=1 real_time=-1"
$RENDERER $PARAMETERS_0
/bin/bash cp /path to /path
```

[image: KDEnLive scripts tab]

Comment: https://userbase.kde.org/Kdenlive/Manual/Rendering#Generating_Rendering_Scripts